# Android XML Layout folders for different devices

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout, android-resources

[image: I have these folders]

I have these folders in my res folder.

[image]
In the device preview, however, only the tablets dafault to the correct layout xml files, which all the phones go to the original layout folder. I tried changing the dp values for the other two folders (320 and 480) but the phones all go to the original layout folder.

Comment: Are you asking about the Android Studio preview, or what happens when you run the app on a device?

Comment: for the android preview, and when i run the emulator it still uses the wrong layout xml

Answer (score 1):

As your layout folders on your project: 
layout-sw600dp means that all the screens with width of 600dp and higher will use this layout folder.

layout-sw480dp - all the screens with width greater than 480dp and smaller than 600dp will use this layout folder.

layout-sw320dp - all the screens with width smaller than 320dp will use this layout folder.

Link to screen sizes in dp:
[screen sizes](https://material.io/tools/devices/)

Android guide: [Android guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources)

Comment: So shouldn't some of the screens (ie nexus 5 and nexus 4) go to the sw320dp

Comment: Nexus 5  width is 360dp, need to use layout from sw320dp folder. try to run on real device...

Comment: tried running on a real device, everything still uses the sw320dp folder (pixel 2, pixel 4, pixel 5, pixel 2 xl)